# Validation rule to prevent field update

Tags: process-builder, validation-rule

**Background**

In opportunity object I've got two fields

- Stage (Initiated, Develop, Submitted, Review, Hold, Closed)
- Status (open, lost, rejected, withdrawn, closed)

**Objective**

I'm trying to create validation rule to prevent Stage being set to Closed when Status = Open.

**What I've done so far**

In process builder, I've got the criteria as AND(ISCHANGED(Stage) = True, Stage = Closed, Status = Open). But I do not know where to go from here.

**Request**

Does anyone know what actions I need to enter into process builder, to prevent the stage field from updating to Closed (or revert it back to its prior value). if Status = Open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process Builder cannot *stop* edits/changes directly; it can only revert changes. Instead, go to Object Manager in Setup, then click on Opportunity, then Validation Rules (If you're in Classic, Setup > Customize > Opportunity > Validation Rules). You can use the formula there.

Comment: Thankyou!! I did a Validation rule where (AND(TEXT(opportunity_status__c) = 'open', TEXT(opportunity_stage) = 'closed'), and it worked like a charm.  I've accepted answer and upvoted, but since I've only got 1 rep on this SE, it didn't get recognized.

Comment: @BobbyHeyer Don't worry about it, I think I have enough rep . Also, you got your first +1. Great question, I meant to upvote earlier!